# Error code 19 on SlqiliteDatabase.Insert();

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having a hard time finding a bug here, I have to ask for a help.

I'm creating ContentValues and inserting them using this simple method:

```
public long insertValues(String tableName, ContentValues values) {      
    return SQLDb.insert(tableName, null, values);   
}
```

Method sure works, I used it many times to insert values to other tables, having problem with only one table which structure is presented on the picture below:

[image: database structure picture]

Method fails as it returns id -1. I did contentValues.toString() before and got this:

```
repeatability=monthly value=1800.0 category_id=17 _id=1 kind=inc name=ECCO
```

Important notes:

- Table is empty in the moment of inserting

What am i missing here?

Comment: Use `insertOrThrow` method to see what is causing the error. [link] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: error code 19: constraint failed

Comment: Does any field in the table has `NOT NULL` constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in some field in the table that has the `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: FLOAT worked fine so far. It was NOT NULL which was causing the problem. Could you add it to the answer so I could accept it?